# How to resize / and add another logical volume without data loss

Tags: partitioning, 16.04, filesystem, lvm

Ubuntu 16.04 installed with these settings "Erase Disk and install Ubuntu" with "Use LVM with the new Ubuntu installation". Now have 3 partitions:

- `/dev/sda1` mounted as `/boot/efi`
- `/dev/sda2` Linux file system mounted as `/boot` and
- `/dev/sda3` Linux LVM as 255 GB LVM2 PV with inside 2 Logical Volume `/dev/ubuntu-vg/root` (247 GB) and `/dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1` (8,5 GB).

Have searched for a clear and safe tutorial to be able to safely shrink the root partition to something like 30 GB (more or less) and create a new Logical Volume with the rest for a home/data partition.

Can't use `system-config-lvm` because of an error. The GUI shows up but doesn't display anything:

> Unable to show VG because it contains features that are not supported in current version of system-config-lvm.

So I need to use the command line but not sure if it takes care of the data on the root partition (got a backup of important data).

Can anybody give me directions on what to do?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67822/how-do-i-combine-two-logical-volumes-that-reside-on-a-single-physical-volume-in/

Answer (score 0):

You need to try LVM terminal mode commands. For that you need to make sure that you have lvm2 package installed.

You can install it by typing:

sudo apt-get install lvm2

After this you can go through the following URLs and play with LVM.

https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm

P.S.: Always use display commands first to view the present volume status. Then you can go for create/resize etc commands as per your need. Think twice before you press enter for resize/remove. I always prefer to do some test setups using a different machine with no important data, learn the thing properly and then apply on a machine with valuable data.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

1. Go to your disk utility.
2. Find your hard disk in the list.
3. Go to one of the settings menu (the one with the two cogs) and select "create a new partition"

Note: I would recommend creating a disk image and downloading it to a bigger disk in case something happens during write.

Another note: If there is more than 4 drives, and you disk is in FAT32 format, create a disk image and install on it another hard drive, and format the drive that you want to partition as NTFS.